# Jenkins as service on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: jenkins

I have to configure Jenkins as service on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, could you please help me to configure the same.
I've tried with chkconfig but it's not working.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what help you need? What are you stuck with it?

Comment: I've tried this link http://www.donaldsimpson.co.uk/2012/01/24/managing-jenkins-as-a-service-and-starting-at-boot-time/ but I don't know how to do that.